# Need help fixing "where" function

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error

An invalid Syntax error keeps getting thrown for line 11 with no obvious solution from my viewpoint

```
# Load libraries import pandas as pd from datetime import timedelta
# Loading dataset, creating duration column, and filtering to negative durations
url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1YV5bKobzYxVAWyB7VlxNH6dmfP4tHBui'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates = ['pickup_datetime', 'dropoff_datetime', 'dropoff_calculated'])
df["duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["duration"])

# Task 1: add 12 hours to dropoff duration for negative durations
df['duration'].where(~(df['duration'] < timedelta(0)), inplace = True, other = 
df['dropoff_datetime'] + timedelta(if >= 12))
                              
df['duration'] = df['dropoff_datetime'] - df['pickup_datetime']

# Task 3: inspect first 10 rows with negative duration
print(df[df['duration'] < timedelta(0)][["pickup_datetime", "dropoff_datetime", "trip_duration", "dropoff_calculated"]].head(10))
```

Comment: `timedelta(if >= 12)` - What is this supposed to mean?  Keep in mind that `if` is a reserved keyword that doesn't make sense in this context

Comment: how would I fix the statement then? I'm trying to convert it so that it calculates on a 12-hour scale rather than a 24-hour scale